# Top bar in Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic is missing

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic

The top (title) bar which includes File, Edit, View is missing in Gnome Classic on Ubuntu 12.04.

On switching to Unity and normal Gnome 3, the top bar was usually merged with the Menu Bar, akin to Mac OS interface. However, I am using the Gnome Classic version.

Can anybody tell me how to enable the top (title) bar of applications?

Answer (score 0):

From [Ans](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142772/ubuntu-12-04-upgrade-top-side-bar-missing?answertab=active#tab-top) :

> This can be caused by multiple reasons. Try to reset unity. To to so, go to terminal
>
> Just press Ctrl+Alt+T to start a user terminal.
>   and type:
>
> unity --reset
>
> try this as well:
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
>
> IF that does not work or you need more info Click Here